# ERD - Subclass with composite key that is different than superclass

Tags: primary-key, entity-relationship, composite-primary-key, erd, visual-paradigm

I am creating an ERD and one of my subclasses has a different PK than its superclass is it ok to do so?

I have a superclass **Accounts** which which has **Username** as its PK and then **BannedAccounts** which has (Foreign Key) **AccountsUsername** and **BanDate** as its PK.

The reason I did so is because the same account can be banned multiple times.

Is it correct?

Here is an image of the diagram:
https://prnt.sc/vfb56o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is fine, and it is common to do this. The table `BannedAccounts` could be called a **fact** table since it forms a time series of data points for an account. On the other hand, the `Accounts` table is a **dimension** table because it is used to categorize fact data.

Another way to talk about it is to categorize entities as **weak** or **strong**. `Account` would probably be a *strong entity* because it does not depend on other entities to exist. In contrast, `BannedAccounts` is a *weak entity* because it's existence is dependent on `Accounts`; it doesn't make sense to talk about which accounts are banned if there is no definition of an account.

To define the relationship, `BannedAccounts` is a **child** and `Accounts` is a **parent** because `BannedAccounts` references the primary key of `Accounts`. The relationship can be further classified as a **strong** (or **identifying**) relationship because the primary key of `BannedAccounts` contains the entire primary key of `Accounts`. If the key for `Accounts` was composite (consisting of more than 1 column), and `BannedAccounts` did not include all of those columns in it's primary key, then the relationship would be called **weak** or **non-identifying**.